# Install Windows 7 On a Computer With No Screen

Tags: windows-7, linux, installation

I have a laptop with the screen dead. It only outputs video on hdmi or vga but not on the lcd screen on it. That means boot up messages, bios settings is not possible in that situation since vga or hdmi output is not available until any os boots up.

I had succeeded installing linux on it with the help of linux usb live disk. It automatically boots up without any action and gives video output on vga and I can take the control.

But I want to install windows 7. This is not possible because when I power up pc with the windows 7 installer usb stick or windows dvd I can't see anything. Is there a way to install windows directly under linux or on network on bootup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an UNATTENDED install. Burn to DVD or install from USB...

1. Use [Windows AIK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYg9yHXD0WM)
2. Use VLite
   ...

Good info at : http://misheska.com/blog/2013/07/26/windows-7-automated-install-settings/